# com.apple.securityserver + com.apple.identityservicesd keep crashing in console. How to fix it?

Tags: mac, macos

My computer has been having a lot of issues recently since I upgraded to Mavericks. Now when I check the console the following processes keep crashing:

`com.apple.securityserver (killing auth hosts + session 1001xx destroyed)`
`com.apple.identityservicesd`

Besides this, the `com.apple.IcoServicesAgent` is about 100-150 MB big. I already did a repair hard disk permissions with Disk Utility as mentioned in another report but this didn't make the file any smaller.

Can someone help me to fix these 2 issues?

Below you can find a part (couldn't post it fully) of the crash report for `com.apple.identityservicesd`. It seems to crash at thread 7.

```
Process:         identityservicesd [730]
Path:            /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDSCore.framework/identityservicesd.app/Conte nts/MacOS/identityservicesd
Identifier:      identityservicesd
Version:         10.0 (1000)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [165]
Responsible:     identityservicesd [730]
User ID:         501


Date/Time:       2013-11-10 23:06:29.767 +0800
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9 (13A603)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  F31CA659-1D52-D473-0A01-705D7ED265DE




Crashed Thread:  7


Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000001


VM Regions Near 0x1:
-->
    __TEXT                 000000010c457000-000000010c4a7000 [  320K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDSCore.framework/identityservicesd.app/Conte nts/MacOS/identityservicesd


Thread 0:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                  0x00007fff91e41a56 semaphore_wait_trap + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib                       0x00007fff9090ca15 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 206
2   libxpc.dylib                            0x00007fff90600733 xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply_sync + 195
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation                0x00007fff89031193 -[CFPrefsPlistSource copyReplyForDaemonMessage:toConnection:error:] + 243
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation                0x00007fff8918b820 __47-[CFPrefsPlistSource alreadylocked_synchronize]_block_invoke_2 + 352
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation                0x00007fff89030a9b withDaemonConnection + 299
6   com.apple.CoreFoundation                0x00007fff890304fb -[CFPrefsPlistSource alreadylocked_synchronize] + 587
7   com.apple.CoreFoundation                0x00007fff89035d8b -[CFPrefsPlistSource alreadylocked_copyKeyList] + 123
8   com.apple.CoreFoundation                0x00007fff89035c2b -[CFPrefsSource copyKeyList] + 43
9   com.apple.CoreFoundation                0x00007fff890e298c __CFPreferencesCopyKeyList_block_invoke + 28
10  com.apple.CoreFoundation                0x00007fff8902f097 +[CFPrefsSource withSourceForIdentifier:user:byHost:container:perform:] + 839
11  com.apple.CoreFoundation                0x00007fff890e28fb CFPreferencesCopyKeyList + 203
12  com.apple.idscore                       0x000000010c516416 0x10c4c8000 + 320534
13  com.apple.idscore                       0x000000010c5163b8 0x10c4c8000 + 320440
14  com.apple.idscore                       0x000000010c512d89 0x10c4c8000 + 306569
15  com.apple.idscore                       0x000000010c512573 0x10c4c8000 + 304499
16  com.apple.idscore                       0x000000010c505795 0x10c4c8000 + 251797
17  libdispatch.dylib                       0x00007fff9090b1d7 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
18  libdispatch.dylib                       0x00007fff909082ad _dispatch_client_callout + 8
19  libdispatch.dylib                       0x00007fff9090ff03 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 333
20  com.apple.CoreFoundation                0x00007fff890a4839 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
21  com.apple.CoreFoundation                0x00007fff8905fb14 __CFRunLoopRun + 1636
22  com.apple.CoreFoundation                0x00007fff8905f275 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
23  com.apple.Foundation                    0x00007fff8bf05a7c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 253
24  com.apple.Foundation                    0x00007fff8bfee70a -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 74
25  com.apple.identityservicesd             0x000000010c458d1d 0x10c457000 + 7453
26  libdyld.dylib                           0x00007fff8b9935fd start + 1


Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                  0x00007fff91e46662 kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib                       0x00007fff9090a43d _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 239
2   libdispatch.dylib                       0x00007fff9090a152 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52


Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                  0x00007fff91e45e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                 0x00007fff925adf08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib                 0x00007fff925b0fb9 start_wqthread + 13


Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                  0x00007fff91e45e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                 0x00007fff925adf08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib                 0x00007fff925b0fb9 start_wqthread + 13


Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                  0x00007fff91e45e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                 0x00007fff925adf08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib                 0x00007fff925b0fb9 start_wqthread + 13


Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                  0x00007fff91e45e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                 0x00007fff925adf08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib                 0x00007fff925b0fb9 start_wqthread + 13


Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                  0x00007fff91e45e6a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                 0x00007fff925adf08 _pthread_wqthread + 330
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib                 0x00007fff925b0fb9 start_wqthread + 13


Thread 7 Crashed:
0   com.apple.MessageProtection             0x000000010c7ca428 readSize + 38
1   com.apple.MessageProtection             0x000000010c7ca7d1 CreateECPublicKeyFrom + 92
2   com.apple.MessageProtection             0x000000010c7c99c0 SecMPPublicIdentityCreateFromBytes + 198
3   com.apple.MessageProtection             0x000000010c7c9b3a SecMPPublicIdentityCreateFromData + 70
4   com.apple.idscore                       0x000000010c511c31 0x10c4c8000 + 302129
5   com.apple.idscore                       0x000000010c510a17 0x10c4c8000 + 297495
6   com.apple.idscore                       0x000000010c50f5a1 0x10c4c8000 + 292257
7   com.apple.imfoundation                  0x00007fff91720562 0x7fff91713000 + 54626
8   com.apple.Foundation                    0x00007fff8bf000de __NSThreadPerformPerform + 229
9   com.apple.CoreFoundation                0x00007fff8906e8f1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
10  com.apple.CoreFoundation                0x00007fff89060062 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 242
11  com.apple.CoreFoundation                0x00007fff8905f7ef __CFRunLoopRun + 831
12  com.apple.CoreFoundation                0x00007fff8905f275 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
13  com.apple.CoreFoundation                0x00007fff891149d1 CFRunLoopRun + 97
14  com.apple.idscore                       0x000000010c50dc65 0x10c4c8000 + 285797
15  com.apple.Foundation                    0x00007fff8bf0370b __NSThread__main__ + 1318
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib                 0x00007fff925ac899 _pthread_body + 138
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib                 0x00007fff925ac72a _pthread_start + 137
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib                 0x00007fff925b0fc9 thread_start + 13


Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                  0x00007fff91e41a1a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                  0x00007fff91e40d18 mach_msg + 64
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation                0x00007fff89060315 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 181
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation                0x00007fff8905f939 __CFRunLoopRun + 1161
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation                0x00007fff8905f275 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 309
5   com.apple.CoreFoundation                0x00007fff891149d1 CFRunLoopRun + 97
6   com.apple.CoreSDB                       0x000000010c7e40f5 0x10c7da000 + 41205
7   com.apple.Foundation                    0x00007fff8bf0370b __NSThread__main__ + 1318
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib                 0x00007fff925ac899 _pthread_body + 138
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib                 0x00007fff925ac72a _pthread_start + 137
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib                 0x00007fff925b0fc9 thread_start + 13


Thread 7 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x00000000ffffffce  rbx: 0x000000010d463ab8  rcx: 0x0000000000000000  rdx: 0x000000010d463a4e
  rdi: 0x000000010d463ac0  rsi: 0x000000010d463ab8  rbp: 0x000000010d463a30  rsp: 0x000000010d463a30
   r8: 0x00007f9f1be33120   r9: 0x00000000000000f6  r10: 0x00007fff94c40a28  r11: 0x00007fff8c5a55b6
  r12: 0x000000010d463ac0  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x0000000000000000  r15: 0x0000000000000000
  rip: 0x000000010c7ca428  rfl: 0x0000000000010216  cr2: 0x0000000000000001

Logical CPU:     2
Error Code:      0x00000004
Trap Number:     14
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sign out your iCloud account in Messages.app, then log in again.

Comment: Why does that fix it?

Comment: @Mark This did fix my problem. Pay attention to the crashed thread in the crash report, it was "com.apple.MessageProtection".

Comment: Thanks Ziming Chen but  somehow it didn't solve the issue :-(

Comment: I also can't log back in into iMessage now :-(
It says "Could not sign in. Please check your network connection and try agin" :-(

Comment: Does "com.apple.identityservicesd" still keep crashing?

Comment: Seems it is not crashing anymore and I can now login into iMessage again :-)
Thanks a bunch for you help!!!

Comment: Iconservicesagent is still very big though :-(
300+ MB

Comment: Force quit it with Activity Monitor.app may be an option.

Answer (score 0):

Dimitry solution did the job for me!

My Messages app was completely dead after update from 10.10.5 to 10.11.1.

I deleted ids.db in safe mode and restarted. Messages did finally boot and then I just had to enter my iCloud account.

thanks!

Marc

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem. Deleting corrupt database at `/Users/[user]/Library/IdentityServices/ids.db` path fixed the issue.